# Iptables and Postfix

Tags: iptables, postfix

Examine configuration of Postfix and iptables, what will be response of mail server and why?

First:

main.cf

```
mynetwork=127.0.0.1/8
smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit_inet_interfaces
```

iptables

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -i lo -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -o lo -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Telnet session

```
telnet localhost 25
hello carlo.ru
mail from:<test@localhost>
rep to:<test@localhost>
data
test
.
exit
```

Second:

main.cf

```
mynetwork=127.0.0.1/8
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks
```

iptables

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -i lo -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -o lo -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Telnet session

```
telnet localhost 25
hello carlo.ru
mail from:<test@localhost>
rep to:<test@localhost>
data
test
.
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your mail server accepts the TCP connection (instead of telnet waiting for the connection to be dropped and you just typing away:)), try the following (you have errors in your SMTP conversation):

```
telnet localhost 25
helo carlo.ru
mail from:<test@localhost>
rcpt to:<test@localhost>
data
test
.
exit
```

It's `helo` or `ehlo` not `hello` and it's also `rcpt to` instead of `rep`.